# Decoupling buttons(2 buttons are toggling at the same time) and show the appropriate button depending on the data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a page where a person can register for a particular course, I am able to display correctly but when doing ng-repeat , all the Register buttons are toggling which is not right, also I would like to display the appropriate button depending on the ID I get back in the data, for instance registration_id : 1 means Already registered(which would mean I should show the cancel button) and registration_id: 2 means, not yet registered(should show the Register button)

Thank you in Advance
HTML

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
    <section class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h3 class="panel-title"> Course Information</h3>
            <span class="registerRoaster pull-right" ng-if="register">register</span>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body course-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <lable class="col-xs-6 text-left h5">Course Name:</lable>
                    <span class="col-xs-6 text-center h5">{{course.name}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <lable class="col-xs-6 text-left h5">Points:</lable>
                    <span class="col-xs-6 text-center h5">{{course.points}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
                <hr/>
            <div class="row">
                <lable class="col-xs-12 pull-left h5"> Description:</lable>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <textarea class="descriptionSize">{{course.description}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <lable class="col-xs-12 pull-left h5"> Agenda:</lable>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <textarea class="descriptionSize">{{course.agenda}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" role="tablist">
<section class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo">
    <h3 class="panel-title"> Available Sessions</h3>
    <hr/>
        </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div ng-repeat="session in course.sessions" class="container">
        <div class="session-item">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="col-xs-12 h5">{{session.session_days[0].start_date | date}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 session-address h5">
                    {{session.location_name}}
                    <lable class="label">location</lable>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 session-room h5">
                    {{session.session_days[0].room}}
                    <lable class="label">room number</lable>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 session-instructor h5">
                    {{session.instructor.name}}
                    <lable class="label">instructor</lable>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 session-action">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="toggleRegister(true)" ng-show="!register">Register</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" ng-click="toggleRegister(false)" ng-show="register">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
</section>
    </div>
```

JS:--

```
 angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope', '$state','$http' , function($scope, $state, $http) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.register = false;
        $scope.init = function(){
            $scope.course =    {
                "course_id": 1,
                "name": "Course Name 1",
                "short_name": "coursename1_ILT",
                "description": "desc",
                "agenda": "agenda here",
                "points": 5,
                "status_id": 2,
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "session_id": 1,
                        "course_id": 1,
                        "status_id": 2,
                        "is_completed": false,
                        "registration": {
                            "registration_id": 1,
                            "registration_type_id": 1
                        },
                        "instructor": {
                            "id": 110,
                            "name": "John Smith"
                        },
                        "session_days": [

                            {
                                "sort_order": 1,
                                "room": "4012V",
                                "duration": 4,
                                "start_date": "2016-11-30"
                            }
                        ],
                        "location_id": 1,
                        "location_name": "ALBANY - A",
                        "max_class_size": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "session_id": 2,
                        "course_id": 2,
                        "status_id": 2,
                        "is_completed": false,
                        "registration": {
                            "registration_id": 2,
                            "registration_type_id": 2
                        },
                        "instructor": {
                            "id": 112,
                            "name": "John Smith"
                        },
                        "session_days": [

                            {
                                "sort_order": 1,
                                "room": "4012V",
                                "duration": 6,
                                "start_date": "2016-12-30"
                            }
                        ],
                        "location_id": 1,
                        "location_name": "ALBANY - A",
                        "max_class_size": 10
                    }]

            };

        };
            $scope.registration = [
                {name: "Registered", id: 1},
                {name: "Not-Registered", id: 2}
            ];
        $scope.toggleRegister = function(status){
            $scope.register = status;
        };
        $scope.init();
    }]
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using register as a global variable.
You should set the registered property into the model repeated, or, if you want to keep it "global" you should add the index parameter to the toggleRegister function

```
$scope.toggleRegister = function(status){
    $scope.register = status;
};
```

becomes

```
$scope.toggleRegister = function(status, session_id){
    // 1. find session with given id
    // 2. set status for that session
};
```

The buttons are toggling together because you have only one variable to rule them all.

```
ng-click="toggleRegister(true)" ng-show="!register"
```

should be

```
ng-click="toggleRegister(true, session.session_id)" ng-show="!session.registration.registration_id == 1"
```

Comment: could you please elaborate :-s